# Generate Sitemap.xml on request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I Know we can generate a sitemap on build and store it in assets folder.

```
www.example.com/sitemap.xml - This is the root level sitemap.
```

But I wanted to know how to generate sitemap on request. For eg.

If user enter the below URL,  I need to capture the request `sitemap.xml`. And in the component I'll have to make a http call to fetch all the sitemap urls which belongs to `moduleA`.

And then serve the sitemap.xml without throwing error or routing to error page ?

```
www.example.com/moduleA/sitemap.xml
```

Is it possible to do it angular ? If so how Do I do it ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, using Angular to handle generating sitemap on request is not possible. You have to handle this in the server. Using Angular SSR or not, your angular app should be served via a server, example express server. Then you can use something like this:

```
app.get("/sitemap.xml", (req, res) => {
  const xml = generatingXML();
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
  res.end(xml);
});
```

Put above code about your catch all route that serve the angular. 
You can use `axios` https://github.com/axios/axios to make api call on the server.